# No Dimensional Array Iteration PHP

Tags: php

Just a small quick fire question, how can I iterate my loop to this

```
(
    8885555512,
    8885551212,
    5555648583,
    4155553695,
    5555228243,
    5554787672,
    4085555270,
    4085553514,
    5556106679,
    5557664823,
    7075551854
)
```

I have tried doing this for loop but didn't worked

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'phone_numbers' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        return response(array(
        'code' => 0,
        'message' =>$validator->errors()->all(),
        'status' => "error",
        ),200);
    }
    else
    {

        $phone_numbers_data = array();
        $phone_numbers = Input::get('phone_numbers');
        print_r($phone_numbers);
        foreach($phone_numbers as $p)
        {
            echo $p;
        }
    }
```

But still getting error as

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach
```

Any Solution?

Comment: typo error updated

Comment: are you sure `$phone_numbers` is array? can you please show what `var_dump` returns

Comment: show us the full print_r output, not just what you are looking at

Comment: yes this is what I have for now, I want to fetch all the values

Comment: should work: https://ideone.com/Fid9hQ

Comment: Judging from OP's other comments. I'm pretty sure the contents of `$phone_numbers` is a string. If you're here to answer the question from OP you'll most likely need to split up his data and convert to array.

Comment: [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) works with arrays (and objects that implement the [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface). Make sure `$phone_numbers` is of one of these types. There is no such thing like a *"No Dimensional Array"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have actual *text* like you've given as input, first take the inner part of phone numbers, then split.

```
$phone_numbers = <<<DATA
(
    8885555512,
    8885551212,
    5555648583,
    4155553695,
    5555228243,
    5554787672,
    4085555270,
    4085553514,
    5556106679,
    5557664823,
    7075551854
)
DATA;


preg_match('#\((.*)\)#sm', $phone_numbers, $matches);
$phone_numbers_as_array = preg_split('#\s*,\s*#sm', trim($matches[1]));
```

now, your phone numbers are actually in an array, not text. Now you can loop over it with `foreach`.

Answer (score 2):

As you have fixed the typo, the only problem seems is like the way you are declaring array. Below code declares an array and loop through it.

```
<?php

$phone_numbers = array(
    8885555512,
    8885551212,
    5555648583,
    4155553695,
    5555228243,
    5554787672,
    4085555270,
    4085553514,
    5556106679,
    5557664823,
    7075551854
);

print_r($phone_numbers);
foreach($phone_numbers as $p)
{
  echo $p;
}
```

Comment: No ! I am making REST Api, mobile team is sending me data in this format only , I am fetching this from a post variable

Comment: Post your complete code, how you are getting value from $_POST variable ?

Comment: well @JayminNoob you forget to mention that, right?

Comment: And what does print_r($phone_numbers) outputs in your case ?

Comment: I think, judging from his comments, that it prints out a string, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
(
8885555512,
8885551212,
5555648583,
4155553695,
5555228243,
5554787672,
4085555270,
4085553514,
5556106679,
5557664823,
7075551854
)
```

this can correct if you ask them to pass instead

```
[
8885555512,
8885551212,
5555648583,
4155553695,
5555228243,
5554787672,
4085555270,
4085553514,
5556106679,
5557664823,
7075551854
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop looks is good.

You can cast a variable to an array in this sense.

```
$var = (array)$arr;
```

Try to cast your Rest return before the loop,

Comment: it is giving me all my data at [0] key like [0]=> ( 5556106679,
    5557664823,
    7075551854
))